# Generic Method Compile Error with Class<T>

Tags: java, generics

I have a method with the following signiture:

```
public <T> T encode(String[] data, Class<T> type)
```

Whenever I invoke it, I get a compile error such as:

```
The method encode(String[], Class<T>) is not applicable for the arguments (String, Class<Integer>)"
```

In this case when I pass it `Integer.class`. (It gives a similar errors for any `Object.class`)

From what I have seen with generic methods, this should work and use `Integer` as `T`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post the invocation code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error message says it all; you are trying to pass in a String and your method expects a String array.

> The method encode(**String[]**, Class) is not applicable for the arguments (**String**, Class)